# Excel 2010 VBA .send error

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have the following code, which works FINE for 10 macros prior to this one (I use a call x, call Y macro), but this one does not want to work.

```
Sub Send_Tips()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Body As String, i As Integer
Dim Mail_Object, nameList As String, o As Variant
    Email_Send_From = ""
     For i = 1 To 1 'use cells 1 to 1 in column "A" where names are stored
If Sheets("Tips").Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
    nameList = nameList & ";" & Sheets("Tips").Range("A" & i).Value
End If
Next
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
        .Subject = "Dealer Action Plans"
        .To = nameList
        .Body = "Please find attached the latest version of the Dealer Action Plans." 
        'Make a copy of the active sheet and save it to
 'a temporary file
 Worksheets("Tips").Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Filename = "Tips.pdf"
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Worksheets("Tips").ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="c:\aaaWork\Tips.pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False

'    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\aaaWork\NC1.PDF", FileFormat:=17

        .Attachments.Add "C:\aaaWork\Tips.PDF"
        .send 'Will send straight away use .display to send manually
       ActiveWorkbook.Close Saved = True
        Kill "C:\aaaWork\Tips.PDF"
End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I get the following error message when the line
    .send 'Will send straight away use .display to send manually
is ran.
Run Time Error '2147467259 (80004005)':
Outlook doesn't recognise one or more names

The sheet name Tips does exist, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your variables are not declared properly. That might help you debug.

Comment: If you change `.send` to `.display`, does the error (or a similar error) persist?

Comment: Also, try moving the block of code where you create the temporary file (`Worksheets("Tips").Activate ... OpenAfterPublish:=False` to *before* `Set Mail_Object...`.

Comment: The display works like a charm, but moving the block doesnt help!

Comment: SOLVED: The display function revealed that the e-mail addresses werent visible to Excel, fixed that and everything is working. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow-up on what I mentioned about the variable declarations... when you do this:

`Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Body As String, i As Integer`

you have not specified a TYPE for `Email_Subject, Email_Send_From` so these are treated as type Variant.  Same with `Mail_Object` on the next line:

`Dim Mail_Object, nameList As String, o As Variant`

Rewrite these lines per below, so that your string variables are correctly declared:

`Dim Email_Subject$, Email_Send_From$, Email_Body$, i As Integer`
`Dim Mail_Object$, nameList As String, o As Variant`

Although these did not cause this particular error, they could certainly cause other errors if the variables are set improperly (e.g., a Variant might contain an object or an array instead of a string which the rest of the code expects, etc.)

Otherwise I would start just by cleaning up the code per above, and then substitute the `.Display` for the `.Send` to troubleshoot and make sure everything is set properly in the Email.